# Sublime Text tmLanguage Syntax highlighting within a capture

Tags: xml, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am creating a custom .tmLanguage file for Sublime Text and I need to be able to highlight the "/" inside a capture here's the code:

```
    <dict>
            <key>begin</key>
            <string>"</string>
            <key>beginCaptures</key>
            <dict>
                <key>0</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>constant.numeric</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
            <key>end</key>
            <string>"</string>
            <key>endCaptures</key>
            <dict>
                <key>0</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>constant.numeric</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>storage.type</string>
</dict>
```

That produces:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5xyb.png

I cant seem to figure out how to highlight that "/" in a different color (specifically the "invalid.deprecated" color) that is shown in the pic above. I've tried many different variations of code, none of which will highlight that dang "/"!!!

Answer (score 1):

You want to add some kind of "inline patterns" that can match things inside of your begin-end match, and then assign the invalid.deprecated scope to that. It's comparable to how most syntax definitions handle escape sequences in strings.

[Here](https://github.com/FichteFoll/CSScheme/blob/65583cbfc58eb4ffafb3177e4363522d56ba8a28/Package/SCSScheme.YAML-tmLanguage#L329-L339) is the version of a package of mine in YAML (and not plist xml bullshit):

```
name: string.quoted.double.css
begin: '"'
beginCaptures:
  '0': {name: punctuation.definition.string.begin.csscheme}
end: '"'
endCaptures:
  '0': {name: punctuation.definition.string.end.csscheme}
patterns:
- name: constant.character.escape.css
  match: \\.
```